# Click with the VBA selenium does not work

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I'm trying to click on the web using VBA+selenium+Chrome
This is my code

```
dim y as webelement

Set y = driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='source']")     ' not working
Set y = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='material-icons md-20 icon' and text()='code']") ' not working
x = driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", y) ' not working

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[13]/div/span").click   ' not working
```

This is HTML
[image]

Chrome version 96.0.4664.110.
ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45
I use the default profile
If I use profile 1, the code works
can anyone help me ?

Comment: what is the difference between the two profiles? Are you sure you are not automatically logged in with one and not with the other?

Answer (score 1):

```
//span[contains(text(),'source')]
```

Would be the right xpath the class isn't source the text is.

Comment: hmmm .... still doesn't work

Is it because of the default profile?

Comment: What website is it?

Comment: https://sellercenter.lazada.co.id/apps/product/publish

Comment: Was wondering what error did you get?

Comment: Cause if it's not found it could be shadowroots or frames.

Comment: Is there an idea for that ?